# I am confused at a step in the proof of Cauchy Criterion otherwise known as Cauchy Condensation

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation, proof-explanation

> Lemma 7.3.6 For any natural number $K$, we have $S_{2^{K+1}-1} \leq T_K \leq 2S_{2^K}$

Where $S_N := \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{N} a_n$ and $T_K := \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{K} 2^ka_{2^k}$

in this proof he uses induction, I'm confused at this part:

$S_{2^{K+1}} = S_{2^K} + \displaystyle \sum_{n=2^K+1}^{2^{K+1}} a_n \geq S_{2^K} +
\displaystyle \sum_{n=2^K+1}^{2^{K+1}} a_{2^{K+1}} = S_{2^K} + 2^Ka_{2^{K+1}}$

im confused how does $\sum_{n=2^K+1}^{2^{K+1}} a_{2^{K+1}} = 2^Ka_{2^{K+1}}$?

in fact how does this notation $\sum_{n=2^K+1}^{2^{K+1}} a_{2^{K+1}}$ even make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sum$$\sum_{n=2^K+1}^{2^{K+1}}a_{2^{K+1}},\tag1$$you are summing $2^K$ numbers, each of which is equal to $a_{2^{K+1}}$. Therefore $(1)$ is equal to $2^Ka_{2^{K+1}}$.

Comment: Well for example $\sum_{n=m}^{N} 5$ does not make any sense. If we let $b_n := 5$ then $\sum_{n=m}^{N} b_n$ makes sense, i guess this is what Tao is doing, just omitting that part. Similarly how do we know there is $2^K$ numbers? is it just simply because $2^K + 1 -(2^{K+1}) = 2^K$?

Comment: I see no difference between $\sum_{n=m}^N5$ and defining $b_n$ as $5$ and then talking about $\sum_{n=m}^Nb_n$; after all, since each $b_n$ is $5$,$$\sum_{n=m}^Nb_n=\sum_{n=m}^N5.$$And the set $\{2^K+1,2^K+2,\ldots,2^{K+1}\}$ has $2^K$ numbers, since $2^{K+1}-2^K=2^K$. More generally, the set $\{a,a+1,a+2,\ldots,b\}$ has $b-(a-1)$ elements.

Comment: Right okay thank you very much for this.